# "Error:(22, 0) CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" how to use git command in build.gradle

Tags: android, git, gradle

I import other people android project with gradle, but I got a problem
when I sync gradle project , it will show

> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

than I read log deteil message ,
it says

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git"

here is my build.gradle file HEAD code:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven' }
mavenCentral()
}

android {
/**
 * Gets the git sha prefix 7
 */
def getCommitSha = { ->
    def sha = "git rev-parse --verify HEAD".execute()
    def formatRule = "cut -b 1-7".execute()
    def shaText = (sha | formatRule).text.trim()
    return shaText
  }
```

please tell me ,how to use git command in build.gradle file?or I lost some .exe?

I already install git.exe ,thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using? Did you add git to your path variable? Are you sure that "cut..." will work? Because that is a linux command and usually not present on windows.

Comment: So unless you have some linux tools installed on your system, the `cut` command will not work because windows does not know this. The `git` command fails, because it is not set in the path variable. Add the path there and fetching the data from `git` will work.

Comment: os is win7 sp1,I have been add git to path variable ,how can i use linux in windows system?  thanks

Comment: There is no simple way to do this. I highly suggest you don't use such tools, but instead use what ever possibilites java and gradle give you. Don't get me wrong... there are ways to get some of the unix tools running on a windows computer. But I have no good experiences with that, and will not lead anyone to destroy his windows like I did.

Comment: but it is customers require.so I must solve it.
Thanks you. so if i install linux tool and it will work normal?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? So what is the output you expect from the function? Sadly even if you were running linux, this code would not work, so I have no real idea what you expect to get? Something like the first 7 characters of the sha hash of the HEAD commit of the current branch?

Comment: I just want to Android Studio can compile this project normal and work,code is customers gave.  but other computer can compile pass,so I think I lose install some application?

Comment: Then you should find out what additional tools are installed on the computers that are compiling this.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I has been solved this problem.
The problem caused by my os is windows but use Linux command.
so when I installed cygwin and add path variable then restart computer,this problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Android studio and go to : Settings -> Version Control -> Git In text box next to "Path to Git Executable" you will see "git.exe",  then you just give it a full path like this:

**C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_ca477551eeb4aea0e4ae9fcd3358bd96720bb5c8\bin\git.exe**

It will work and enjoy coding.